# in jquery comment system, use hide() and fadeIn('slow') to new comment only and not to all

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jquery and php code which is used in a comment system similar to facebook.

User types a comment and then post it. I use hide() and fadeIn('slow') in order the comment posted to appear in a nice look. My only problem is that `hide()` and `fadeIn('slow')` works for all comments posted.

I want to make it work only for the new comment posted each time. Any idea how to correct my code in order to do this?

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){                           
    $("#comment_process").click(function(){
        if($("#comment_text").val() != ""){ 
            $.post("comments.php?action=post", { comment: $("#comment_text").val() }, function(data) {
                $(".comments").html(data).hide().fadeIn('slow');
                $("#comment_text").val("");
            });
        } 
    });   
    });   
</script>

<div class="comment_container">
    <div class="comment_form">
        <textarea id="comment_text" placeholder="type..."   style="font-size:11pt;  color:green;  resize:none ">    </textarea>
        <input type="button" id="comment_process" value="Post"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="comments">  <?php include_once("comments.php");?>  </div>
```

comments.php used in order to store and retreive comments from my database.

Comment: I don't know what your comments html structure it, but lets say comments are in `<li>` tags. If you always return ALL comments, then mark new comments with class, example: `<li class="new">`. And then with jQuery show/hide/fade only new ones.

Comment: any example how to do this?

Comment: Which part? Marking new comments? Or hide/fade new comments?

Comment: hide/fade new comments

Comment: `$('.comments').html(data).find('.new').hide().fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: You want it to work for a single new comment, or for all comments the user hasn't yet seen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the order in which your comments update(Asc or Desc):

If your new comment comes first then use

```
$(".comments:first-child").html(data).hide().fadeIn('slow');
$(".comments").first().html(data).hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

else use

```
$(".comments:last-child").html(data).hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

for more easiness, you can look at these tutorials
[using :first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [using .first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: it use it again to all comments, and not only to the new posted comment

Comment: i don't know why it didn't worked I haven't tried the code at my end, adding one more snippet, might that help.

Comment: thanks for help but still nothing...do it again for all comments, not for the new one that I want

Comment: hey I got this, it worked in my css, try it, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: now there's only one thing left to do...add a different class to your newly added comment, and remove that class from other elements(I know the other elements do not have that class, this will help when you add one more comment as the previous comment was new it needs to be made old), till then i'll try to find a valid way.

Answer (score 0):

You could always assign a data- attribute to the post and then use

```
$('.comments[data-id=xxxxx]').hide().fadeIn();
```

to fade it in.

You can assign as many data- attributes as you want, they just have to start with data-, e.g. data-id, data-name, data-xxxxxx.

Assigning the attribute is done like this:

```
<div class="comments" data-id="xxxxx">
```

replace xxxxx by anything you want of course, e.g. new, 1, last...

As your jquery selector is limiting the selection to the element with that attribute it will only hide and fade in the comment you want,  data- attributes can be used for loads of purposes.

Comment: did it. still nothing

Comment: it seems like comments.php returns all comments after posting... replacing the actual content in your comments div

you will need a different approach by adding the post to the div... using .add()

for example $('.comments').add(data);

you will of course need the comments.php return only the last post... in a hidden tag, so you can then fade it in

Comment: this approach looks nice...any idea how to change my code in order to do this?

Comment: You'll have to change the 'echo' part at the end of comments.php, returning the html for the comment you're saving. I can't tell you how exactly as you didn't post the code of that file.